# Dynamic form behaving properly with Chrome, not with Firefox

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, firefox

I'm working with Ionic (thus Angular), and I have a form where I check if the user filled all the required fields and display an error line otherwise. The "submit" button is disabled until every field is filled as required. Also, the field "date" is supposed to make it possible to select a date from a calendar (coming from the format "date" in the input).

This behaviour is working perfectly with Chrome, but with Firefox the button remains disabled even though the form is filled out. I took some screenshots of the issue because I struggled at reproducing the example on a jsFiddle.

**On Chrome**

[image: Working example on Chrome]

**On Firefox**

[image: Buggy example on Firefox]

**HTML:**

```
<form name="signupForm" class="signupForm" novalidate="" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <div class="list">
        <p ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required && !signupForm.email.$pristine" style="color:red;">* Enter an email.</p>
        <label class="item item-input" ng-class="">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
        </label><br/>
        <p ng-show="signupForm.firstname.$error.required && !signupForm.firstname.$pristine" style="color:red;">* Enter a name.</p>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
        </label><br/>
        <p ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.required && !signupForm.password.$pristine" style="color:red;">* Enter a password.</p>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" required>
        </label><br/>
        <p style="text-align:left; margin-left:4%;">Birth date:</p>
        <p ng-show="signupForm.date.$error.required && !signupForm.date.$pristine" style="color:red;">* Enter a birth date.</p>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="date" name="date" ng-model="date" required><br/>
        </label><br/>

        <p style="text-align:left; margin-left:4%;">Gender :</p>
        <div class="gender">
            <select name="gender" ng-model="gender" required>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </div><br/>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-round button-assertive" type="submit" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid" ng-click="submitSignup(email, firstname, password, dateBorn, gender)">Signup</button><br/>
</form>
```

It is not relevant that I post the JS code because it registers the user in the database and that's it. Here, the problem seems to come from the form itself and not what happens after submitting it, given that it's impossible to submit it with the disabled button.

I suspect that the problem is coming from the "gender" div, because it seemed to work properly without it, and I am not certain that my implementation is the best way to insert a "select" in a form. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you have a look to [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44155343/4927984), I tried to explain deeply the problem with date inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input date` is not supported in Firefox. Firefox converts them to `input text`. That's why angular thinks the field is invalid. I suggest you use `<select>` elements for dates:

```
<select name="dob_year" ng-model="dob.year" required>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2015</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_month" ng-model="dob.month" required>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_day" ng-model="dob.day" required>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) for date input:

> **In browsers that do not
>   yet support the HTML5 date input, a text element will be used**. In that
>   case, text must be entered in a valid ISO-8601 date format
>   (yyyy-MM-dd), for example: `2009-01-06`.

Since many modern browsers do
not yet support this input type, it is important to provide cues to
users on the expected input format via a placeholder or label.

Here is an example of a date input, that works on every browser, including ones which does not support date input:

```js
angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
  .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.example = {
       value: new Date(2013, 9, 22)
     };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" ng-app="dateInputExample" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <input type="date" name="input" ng-model="example.value" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" required/>

   <div role="alert">
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.date">Not a valid date!</span>
   </div>

   <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

If you want to keep your date format, I would suggest you to use the [AngularUI datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), without using date inputs.